How to prevent LazyInitializationException in Spring Batch Step with Parallel Chunks and Lazy-Loaded Collections using JpaPagingItemReader?
I’m working on a Spring Batch job with parallel chunk processing. The problem I’m facing is a LazyInitializationException due to nested lazy-loaded collections in my JPA entities.
I’m using JpaPagingItemReader for reading, JpaTransactionManager for managing transactions, and SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor for parallel processing.
Setup:

Spring Boot: 3.3.4
Spring Batch: 5.1.2
Transaction Manager: JpaTransactionManager
Task Executor: SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor

Simple example:
Customer entity:
@Entity
public class Customer {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;
}

Order entity:
The @OneToMany relation is FetchType.LAZY by default.
@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Type> types;

    // Other @OneToMany collection fields...

}

Spring Batch Step Configuration:
I’m using a JpaPagingItemReader and an ItemProcessor. The step is parallelized using a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.
@Bean
public JpaPagingItemReader<Customer> customerItemReader(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder<Customer>()
            .name("customerItemReader")
            .entityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
            .queryString("SELECT c FROM Customer c")
            .pageSize(100)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step processCustomersStep(JobRepository jobRepository,
                         PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                         JpaPagingItemReader<Customer> customerItemReader,
                         ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> customerItemProcessor,
                         ItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter,
                         TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
    return new StepBuilder("processCustomersStep", jobRepository)
            .<Customer, Customer>chunk(100, transactionManager)
            .reader(customerItemReader)
            .processor(customerItemProcessor)
            .writer(customerItemWriter)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .build();
}

When running the batch job, I get the following error when accessing the lazy-loaded order or its nested types collection in the ItemProcessor:
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.myapp.Order.types: could not initialize proxy - no Session

What I’ve tried:

Fetching with JOIN FETCH: I can’t use JOIN FETCH because the
Order entity contains multiple nested lazy-loaded collections,
leading to large, inefficient queries.
Since I am using JpaTransactionManager, I assumed it would manage
the transaction scope properly, but the LazyInitializationException
still occurs when accessing the nested lazy-loaded collections in
the ItemProcessor.

Question:
How can I prevent the LazyInitializationException in a Spring Batch step with parallel chunks when using JpaPagingItemReader and JpaTransactionManager?
Should I handle the EntityManager differently, or is there another pattern to process entities with nested lazy-loaded collections in parallel?
UPDATE (processor, writter and JPA transaction manager)
Item processor:
In the ItemProcessor, I’m creating a new Customer instance and copying the nested Order and its associated Types. This requires accessing the lazy-loaded collections in the ItemProcessor, which is where the LazyInitializationException occurs.
@Component
public class CustomerItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> {

    @Override
    public Customer process(Customer customer) throws Exception {
        Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setTypes(customer.getOrder().getTypes()));
        newCustomer.setOrder(order);
        return newCustomer; 
    }

}

Item writer:
The ItemWriter uses the injected EntityManager to persist the processed entities.
@Component
public class CustomerItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Customer> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public CustomerItemWriter(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Chunk<? extends Customer> chunk) throws Exception {
        chunk.getItems().forEach(entityManager::persist);
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }

}

JPA transaction manager:
The JpaTransactionManager is used to manage the transaction scope within the batch job.
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }


please also add the relevant code for the processor, writter and JpaTransactionManager.

@PanagiotisBougioukos I updated the question with the required information.

Why write your own writer instead of using the default one. Use FETCH JOIN to identify which collections need to be eagerly loaded or write a better query.

@M.Deinum By “default writer,” do you mean that if I don’t register a custom writer, Spring Batch will use the default one provided? Regarding JOIN FETCH, I’ve attempted that approach, but the entity contains several nested lazy-loaded collections, which causes the JpaPagingItemReader to fail. Could you clarify what you mean by “write a better query”? I’m open to suggestions on how to approach this more effectively.

@Oboe Can you attach a full stack trace of the error to your question?

Default writer as in the default JpaItemWriter no need to write one yourself. Better query, write a query that only selects what you need. Your comment also hints at that the code you show here isn't representative for what you really have. I also wonder what the error is you got when using FETCH JOIN.
